# CS0173 compile error on a ternary with different return types

Tags: c#, oop

Consider this example:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class A{}

class B : A{}
class C : A{}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        GetSomething1(true);
    }

    static A GetSomething1(bool oneOrAnother)
    {
        return oneOrAnother ? new B() : new C(); // throws a compile error
    }

    static A GetSomething2(bool oneOrAnother)
    {
        return oneOrAnother ? (A)(new B()) : new C(); // no error
    }

    static A GetSomething3(bool oneOrAnother)
    {
        return oneOrAnother ? new B() : (A)(new C()); // no error
    }

    static A GetSomething4(bool oneOrAnother)
    {
        return oneOrAnother ? (A)(new B()) : (A)(new C()); // no error
    }
}
```

A ternary in GetSomething1 generates

**error CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between `B' and `C'**

I cannot understand why since both B and C can perfectly be casted to A (they extend from it) and it the further examples it is sufficient to explicitly cast only one of them to get the ternary working

Comment: The rule for ternary expressions is that the two possible results either have to be the same type, or one of them can be safely cast to the other. The compiler will not go looking for a safe third base-class that can be used for both. So you will have to specify that one of those two expressions is of the base class instead, like `? (A)new B() : new C()`,

Comment: [See this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2460) -- this is proposed for C# 9

Comment: [Type inference woes, part one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/type-inference-woes-part-one) by Eric Lippert: "If neither type goes to the other, then notice that we do not attempt to find the "nearest encompassing type""

Comment: Interestingly, Java allows this...

Comment: The C# 9 proposals, as I understand them, is that they're opening up some expressions to allow automatic conversions to a target type, when such a target type is present. In the code in the question, the target type for the first expression would be `A`, and since both `B` and `C` can be cast to `A`, it will be allowed. You still cannot do `var x = oneOrAnother ? new B() : new C();` as there is no type to target, but you could do `A x = ...`. Basically, if I understand it correctly, you add the way the expression is used into the mix and which type the usage is expecting.